# Excel named range starting with C and a digit

Tags: excel, vba, named-ranges

I'm working on a macro where I need to name a bunch of ranges and I've just run into an obscure limitation.

[Apparently](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2017/07/11/excel-name-named-range-define-use/#excel-name-rules) named ranges can be a single letter except 'r', 'R', 'c', or 'C', which, when typed into the Excel Name Box are shortcuts for selecting the entire row or column of the active cell (a functionality I've never needed and can't imagine myself ever needing).

Unfortunately for me: a) I need to name ranges with the format `/^C\d+_.*/`, and b) while the little bit of documentation I've seen on this (not officially from Microsoft) says you're just restricted from using the single letter C, I'm finding that I can't use any name ranges matching that regex.

Here's an example of what I'm running into:

```
Sub test()
    On Error Resume Next

    ' These work:
    ThisWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="A0", RefersTo:=Range("A1")
    ThisWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="C0", RefersTo:=Range("A1")
    ThisWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="D0", RefersTo:=Range("A1")
    ThisWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="A1_Test", RefersTo:=Range("A1")
    ThisWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="A1Test", RefersTo:=Range("A1")
    ThisWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="Test_A1", RefersTo:=Range("A1")
    ThisWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="D1_Test", RefersTo:=Range("A1")
    ThisWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="D1Test", RefersTo:=Range("A1")
    ThisWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="Test_C1", RefersTo:=Range("A1")
    ThisWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="Capricious", RefersTo:=Range("A1")

    ' These fail:
    ThisWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="C1_Test", RefersTo:=Range("A1")
    ThisWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="C1Test", RefersTo:=Range("A1")

    Debug.Print "Named Ranges:"
    Dim nm As Name
    For Each nm In ActiveWorkbook.Names
        Debug.Print vbTab & nm.Name
    Next nm
    
End Sub
```

Notice that I can use names where C is replaced with other letters in that regex, and I can use names starting with C but not followed by a digit, but anything I've tried matching that regex fails.

Am I missing something? Is there actually a way to use a named range like "C1_Test"?

I'm in Office 365 if that's relevant.

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Seems like "resembles" a cell address also includes "starts with" a cell address. I think the closest you'll be able to come is to have an underscore as either the first character, or as an intervening character.  Eg: `_C1Test` or `C_1Test`.

Comment: Look up `R1C1` address notation for Excel. You are not allowed to name cells that conflict with range addresses, either `A1` style or `R1C1` style. It is not a bug.

Comment: For example you cannot name a range `A1` as that name is the address of the first cell in a worksheet. If you could name another range `A1` then Excel would have no way of knowing which `A1` you were referring to in any formula. The exact same thing applies to names that conflict with addresses in `R1C1` style. Excel will not allow you to create ambiguity with names that conflict with range addresses.

Comment: @ExcelHero Thanks for the feedback. I understand I can't use an exact existing cell address as a named range and why. It's not being able to start a name with `C\d+` that seems like a bug to me. Again, note that "A1_Test" is OK, while "C1_Test" is not, so this is not just an over-zealous extension of the prohibition on names matching matching existing cell addresses. If the latter is prohibited for being "too much like a cell address", then the former should as well.

Comment: `R` and `C` are special cases, since they are also used in `R1C1` notation. And, I agree that the naming restrictions are not well documented.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Based on the comments so far, I was not missing some naming trick, and there's no way to use "C1_Test" as a named range. So as suggested I prepended each named range with an underscore. That's OK since most users won't look closely at named ranges; it would be more annoying if this (ill-documented) restriction applied to sheet names too. If you want to re-post your comment as an answer, I'll accept it. If not, I'll answer myself for posterity. Thanks.

Comment: @SSilk Done. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like "resembles" a cell address also includes "starts with" a cell address. I think the closest you'll be able to come is to have an underscore as either the first character, or as an intervening character. Eg: `_C1Test` or `C_1Test`

`R` and `C` are special cases, since they are also used in `R1C1` notation.

And, I agree that the naming restrictions are not well documented